# Overwrite 'require' in child-theme

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, child-theme

I'm trying to customise the Storefront theme from WooCommerce, by creating a child-theme. I've already done a couple of things in the 'functions.php' file, but I can't seem to overwrite the 'require' in the parent.

In my child-theme's 'functions.php' I'm trying to overwrite the file it requires in the parent's 'functions.php'. Unfortunately, when I do this, it keeps showing the required file the parent called for.

Below is the line of code I've tried:

```
require '/inc/storefront-template-hooks.php';
```

&

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/storefront-template-hooks.php';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A functions file in a child theme does not override the functions from the parent theme, but adds them. So the file in the parent theme is always loaded (afaik). I see that the parent theme file has nothing but add_actions. What you can do is first 'undo/delete these actions (by a hook) and then add your own.

Comment: As Beee says, child themes add to, rather than replace, so you can't replace an included file from the parent theme. However, as that particular file is just setting up a load of action hooks, you can look at what it's doing and add `remove_action()` lines to your *functions.php* to unhook those that you don't want. For example, in the file is `add_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_credit', 20 );` so you can have `remove_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_credit', 20 );` and, voila, no more footer credit!

Answer (score -2):

according to the documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

> If a child theme is being used, the absolute path to the parent theme
>   directory will be returned. Use **get_stylesheet_directory()** to get the
>   absolute path to the child theme directory.

I hope you find it useful :)

Comment: As Beee commented in the question, child theme does not override the functions from the parent theme. Your answer is irrelevant.